# linux command line just goes to next line

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, putty

sometimes in linux when i run commands and gets an error. I only see a blank line with nothing in it, not even this comes up:

```
[root@ip-172-31-41-7 ec2-user]#
```

when I type any command when I have nothing on the line to start with and hit enter, it just goes to the next line...I usually fix this by restarting putty and going back into the console but I figure there has to be an easier way to do this...

```
login as: ec2-user
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Last login: Sun Aug 24 17:56:42 2014 from pool-108-51-205-159.washdc.fios.verizon.net
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-41-7 ~]$ sudo su
[root@ip-172-31-41-7 ec2-user]# hive --service hwi
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hwi-*.war: No such file or directory
14/08/24 18:02:32 INFO hwi.HWIServer: HWI is starting up
14/08/24 18:02:33 INFO mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
14/08/24 18:02:33 INFO mortbay.log: jetty-6.1.26
14/08/24 18:02:33 INFO mortbay.log: Extract /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.13.0.2.1.4.0-632.jar to /tmp/Jetty_localhost_9998_hive.hwi.0.13.0.2.1.4.0.632.jar__hwi__.iiras8/webapp
14/08/24 18:02:33 INFO mortbay.log: Started SocketConnector@localhost:9998
clear
;
cd /usr/
```

Comment: That indicates that you don't know how to use linux.... you're not backgrounding the process is my first guess.

Comment: When you see 'no prompt', think 'previous command has not finished yet'.  So as @tink said, there's a good chance that `hive` is still running.  If you want it to run but return control to the terminal, add an `&` at the end.  Consider sending its logging output to a file, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't get a prompt, this indicates that the previous command hasn't finished. You can either:

1. Background the process when you run it by appending '&' at the end of the command
2. Suspend the process by pressing Ctrl-Z - this will suspend (pause) the process and give you a prompt back. You can continue running the process in the background by running 'bg'.
3. If you no longer care about the process, you can kill it by pressing Ctrl-C

Answer (score 0):

If the terminal is broken the command `reset` often helps to set it back to normal operation. But, I don't know if this works with Putty as well.